# Using stackblur with canvas do not blur my image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have this javascript code:

```
// Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var cctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var buff = document.createElement("canvas");
buff.width = canvas.width;
buff.height = canvas.height;

  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    cctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
  };
// Slider
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
slider.addEventListener("change", function() {
    cctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    stackBlurImage(imageObj, canvas, slider.value,false);
}, false);
```

And Here HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0" id="slider" />
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="dist/stackblur.js"></script>
```

Why my image do not get blur effect when i drag the slider please ? is there any false in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first mistake as correctly pointed out by @jafarbtech is indeed a typo : 
you wrote `StackBlurImage(`, while the correct syntax is `StackBlur.image(`.

Then, if you've got the same error as in @jafarbtech's answer, it is because StackBlur uses `getImageData` to read the pixel data of your images before applying the blurring algo.

Here your image is sent while breaking the CORS restriction, which does taint the canvas, meaning that any export methods will be blocked (including getImageData).  Hence the plugin can't do anything on your tainted canvas.

To circumvent this, pass only images from the same domain as your script <sub>(beware : `file://` protocol doesn't work either)</sub>.

In the following demo, I will use an other solution which requires the server providing the resource to be correctly set-up.

```js
// Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var cctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var buff = document.createElement("canvas");
buff.width = canvas.width;
buff.height = canvas.height;

  var imageObj = new Image();
  // this will make CORS happy because the server is well configured
  imageObj.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  // Easiest is to always host your images on your own server
  imageObj.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8q8sjnqmmto13h5/lionCMYK.jpg';
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = imageObj.height;
    canvas.height = imageObj.height;
    cctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
  };
// Slider
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
slider.addEventListener("change", function() {
    StackBlur.image(imageObj, canvas, slider.value,false);
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stackblur-canvas/1.4.0/stackblur.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0" id="slider" />
</div>
```

Comment: btw, i think you don't need "buff" anymore. single canvas declaration is enough.

Answer (score 0):

blur image with proper function

```js
// Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var cctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var buff = document.createElement("canvas");
buff.width = canvas.width;
buff.height = canvas.height;

  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    cctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
  };
// Slider
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
slider.addEventListener("change", function() {
    cctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
                StackBlur.canvasRGB(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, slider.value);
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<div>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="slider" />
</div>
<img id="srcimg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgm7x.jpg?s=328&g=1" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.cssscript.com/demo/fast-gaussian-blur-for-canvas-stackblur-js/dist/stackblur.js"></script>
```

Comment: This didn't work the problem ... please try it yourself.